# Is it possible to change the content of a cell with VBA to make it a formula?

Tags: excel, vba

I've begun using macros last week so I'm really a beginner. I have a page containing a lot of formulas and I want to have another one containing the same things except I would need them to be conserved as something else than formulas to save memory.

For now every cell that should contain a formula is formulated like this :

```
§=EQUIV(F7;INDIRECT(A2);0)
```

I tried recording a macro in which I replace every "§" by "", but it doesn't work. After a few other tests I determined that I could not replace characters that would turn a cell into a formula this way, but maybe I am missing something ?

Comment: `§=EQUIV(F7;INDIRECT(A2);0)` is not a formula to begin with, it's a piece of text. What does it mean that you want to conserve memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can use this code:

```
Sub ToFormula()
   With Range("A1")
      .FormulaLocal = Replace(.Value, Chr(167), vbNullString)
   End With
End Sub
```

`A1` is an address of the cell containing formula to change.
If there are more cells to convert you can use Excel `Substitute` function:

```
Sub ToFormula1()
   With Range("A1:A3")
      .FormulaLocal = Application.Substitute(.Value, Chr(167), vbNullString)
   '  another way
   '  .FormulaLocal = Application.Replace(.Value, 1, 1, vbNullString)
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It works when there is only one cell in Range, but when I want to expand it I encounter an error 13 message. Here's what I wrote :

`Sub ToFormula()
   With Range("A1:A5")
      .FormulaLocal = Replace(.Value, Chr(167), vbNullString)
   End With
End Sub`

Comment: If it is more than one cell, use `For Each myCell in Range("A1:A5")`  `With myCell` [...] `Next`